# Ubuntu 14.04.3 installation error (screenshot included)

Tags: 14.04

I need help resolving the following issue that I'm facing during installation of Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo Z510 PC.

I created a bootable USB which works fine, but just after clicking either 'Try Ubuntu without installing' or 'Install Ubuntu' on the main screen, Ubuntu loading screen comes, after which I get the following error:
[image]

```
Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0
ACPI PCC probe failed
nouveau E[PIBUS]... HUBO:...
nouveau E[PIBUS]... GPCO:...
nouveau E[PBUS]... MMIO read of ... FAULT...
Busybox v1.21.1
(initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the boot process, the Live environment is losing connection to the USB stick and thus cannot read the SquashFS image containing the live environment filesystem.

If you have your USB stick plugged into a USB 3.0 port, try connecting it to a USB 2.0 port, otherwise it sounds like something didn't go right with your USB creation, or you have another drive on your Z510 that is interfering with the live boot process.

I would re-make your boot USB stick. If you're a Windows user, download the [Rufus for Windows tool](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and make your boot USB stick from ISO that way, otherwise if you have access to another working Ubuntu system, use the USB Creator Tool there to make it.